# Dataframe Number of Followers for List of Twitter Accounts

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use Tweepy to get the number of followers for a list of twitter accounts, some of which are inactive/suspended. So far I have imported an excel file where one column is all the twitter usernames and another column would be the number of followers for that given account.

I want to iterate through the twitter handle column, remove any inactive/suspended usernames from the dataframe, then iterate through the revised dataframe and populate the number of followers column with the number of followers for each account using Tweepy. I know this will have to be done with two for loops and am looking for help with the first: I'm stuck on how to iterate through the column and remove these inactive accounts.

Here's the head of the dataframe for reference - I'd like to populate the Twitter Followers column and replace the NaNs with the number of twitter followers. 
[image]
So far I've written an exception into my code that flags for specific Tweepy errors like inactive/suspended accounts.

I need help writing the first for loop that removes rows from the dataframe for inactive twitter accounts. Currently when I run this I get no output.

My code so far:

```
import tweepy
import sys
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)


df = pd.read_excel('/Downloads/inc5k_twitterhandles_2.xlsx', sheet_name=0) 
usernames = df['Twitter Handle'].tolist()
rows_to_drop = []

for i in df['Twitter Handle']:
    try:
        user_followers=api.friends_ids(id=i)# this returns the interger value of the user
    except tweepy.error.TweepError as t:
        if t.message[0]['code'] == 50: #Code for user not found error
            rows_to_drop.append(i)
        elif t.message[0]['code'] == 88: # The code for the rate limit error
            time.sleep(15*5) # Sleep for 15 minutes

df.drop(df.index[rows_to_drop], inplace=True )

print(df.head())
```